# Basic question about limit

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

I am new to limit. I have a function $f(x)=x^2$ for $x \neq 2$ and $f(2)=1$. I want to prove that $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) = 4$. I am unsure about my work:

We want to show $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0$ such that $0<|x-2|<\delta \implies |f(x)-4|<\epsilon$.

$|f(x)-4| < \epsilon$

$|x^2-4| < \epsilon$

$-\epsilon < x^2 -4 < \epsilon$

$4-\epsilon < x^2 < 4+\epsilon$

$\sqrt{4-\epsilon} < x < \sqrt{4+\epsilon}$ for $\epsilon \leq 4$

$\sqrt{4-\epsilon} -2 < x-2 < \sqrt{4+\epsilon} -2$

We can choose $\delta = min( 2-\sqrt{4-\epsilon}, \sqrt{4+\epsilon}-2)$ for $\epsilon \leq 4$. For $\epsilon > 4$, we can choose a sufficiently  small value of $\delta$ (say $\delta=0.0001$ )

Edit 1: Removed $|\sqrt{4-\epsilon}-2|< |x-2| < |\sqrt{4+\epsilon}-2|$

---

Is it correct? Are there any thing to improve?

Comment: A typical $\epsilon, \delta$ proof is not about solving inequalities. You need to leave the algebraic mode when learning calculus/analysis.

Comment: The usage of square roots here is in fact circular. In general when doing an $\epsilon, \delta$ proof for some function $f$ you can't make use of its inverse function $f^{-1}$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The book tells me to solve it using algebraic method. It's not circular at all if it's valid.

Comment: You can and should use algebra but only restricted to $+, -, \times, /$ and not operations like $\sqrt{\dots} $. The fact that square roots exist is dependent on continuity of $x^2$ and that is what is needed in this question. That's what makes it circular. Also I request again not to solve inequalities. That's not what definition of limit says.

Answer (score 2):

much simpler way to prove is following.first consider $\delta_1 = 1$ so $0<|x-2|<1$ implies $4<x+2<5$

$$|x^2-4| = |x+2|. |x-2|< 5.|x-2|  < \epsilon  \implies |x-2| < \frac{\epsilon}{5}$$

call this $\delta_2 = \epsilon/5.$ So  we have that $\delta = \min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{5}\}$

Comment: Ok, that's nice. Is there anything wrong with mine?

Comment: @Adola . Added an argument to show that your proof is correct.

Comment: The first equivalence does not hold in general. If $-2<x<0.5$, for example, then $|x| < \min{\{0.5, |-2|\}} = 0.5$ is false.

Comment: If we take $a=1$ and $b=-1.5$, then the other implication also fails. We'd otherwise get $|x| < 1$ implies $1<x<-1.5$. Did you mean to have some constraints on $a$ and $b$ here?

Comment: Counterexample: $a = 1, b = -1.5$. Then $\min{\{|1|, |-1.5|\}} = 1$. Now, for example, if $x = 0.5 = |x|$, then $|x| < 1$ is true. On the other hand, $a = 1 < x = 0.5 < -1.5$ is false. So the implication is false.

Answer (score 2):

You are close. But what happens when you take $\epsilon = 0.1$ for instance? Also, why should $$|\sqrt{4-\epsilon}-2|< |x-2| < |\sqrt{4+\epsilon}-2|$$ imply $$\sqrt{4-\epsilon} -2 < x-2 < \sqrt{4+\epsilon} -2?$$

**Edit**. You may pick $\delta := \min{\{\sqrt{4 + \varepsilon} - 2, \sqrt{8}-2\}}$. To prove this $\delta$ works, you may need the inequality $$\sqrt{4-\varepsilon} < -\sqrt{4+\varepsilon}+4$$ for $0 < \varepsilon \leq 4.$

This inequality is also the reason why your choice of $\delta$ works for $\varepsilon\leq 4$; furthermore, it shows one of the terms in your $\min$ is not required as it is always bigger than the other.

Comment: Ok, I removed that part. How about now?

Comment: Better. But if I give you $\epsilon=0.1$, which delta will you be giving back to me?

Comment: Based on my proof, I will give $min(\sqrt{4+0.1}-2, 2-\sqrt{4-0.1})=\sqrt{4.01}-2 \approx 0.02$

Comment: What is $2-\sqrt{4-0.1}$?

Comment: It's a number bigger than $\sqrt{4.01} -2$. Is there a point that I am missing?

Comment: In facnt your lower bound by taking $\epsilon=1$ is $0.0248$, while the upper bound is $0.025$...so I think it is ok

Comment: @Adola You are right! It is a bigger number. Sorry if I was too convoluted. What I am hinting at is this: when is $2-\sqrt{4-\epsilon} < \sqrt{4+\epsilon} - 2$ true?

Comment: So if you choose $ \delta = min( 2-\sqrt{4-\epsilon}, \sqrt{4+\epsilon}-2)$, what happens if $ x-2 \in ( \sqrt{4-\epsilon} -2, 2- \sqrt{4-\epsilon})$